# logical OR existence test for shell variables under bash

Tags: bash, shell

I need to perform some logic based on if shell_var_1 OR shell_var_2 is set under bash.

If I use #!/bin/sh, I could just use:

```
if [ "$shell_var_1" -ne "0" -o "$shell_var_2" -ne "0" ] ; then
 logic
fi
```

This just uses "-o" from test (http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?test)

However, if I specify #!/bin/bash, and want to use the '-v' option to test the shell variable's existence (added from bash 4.2 onwards), how'd I go about doing the same?

Ref: https://tiswww.case.edu/php/chet/bash/bash.html

```
if [ -v shell_var_1 -o -v shell_var_2 ] ; then
 logic
fi
```

^ Is this considered correct? Am I not mixing bash and the test operator?

Comment: It works for me (bash 4.3.33). As far as mixing bash and the test operator, I doubt it is, since the bracket operators are a builtin in bash (unlike some older systems where there was actually a `/bin/[` executable, or a symlink to `/bin/test`). If you're worried about doing canonical bash, just use double brackets and the `||` logical OR operator. Btw, my system does indeed have `/usr/bin/[`, but `type [` reveals that `[` is a shell builtin, meaning that unless you specifically call `/usr/bin/[`, you're using the shell builtin and not the executable.

Comment: Don't use `-o` or `-a`. They aren't portably well behaved. Use `||` and `&&` between `[ ... ]` tests. `[`/`test` are both built-in in bash (and other shells) at this point but the external binaries still exist on many/most(/all?) systems too.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
[[ $shell_var_1 || $shell_var_2 ]]
```

...is a very succinct and idiomatic way to write this in bash, compatible back to ancient releases, assuming that you consider a variable set to an empty value not to exist.

---

If you want a portable alternative which treats variables set to zero-byte values as unset, then

```
[ -n "$shell_var_1" ] || [ -n "$shell_var_2" ]
```

...will serve.

---

If you want a portable alternative that treats variables set to empty values as existing, then

```
[ -n "${shell_var_1+set}" ] || [ -n "${shell_var_2+set}" ]
```

...will do this.

---

If you really want to use `-v` (thus, treating variables set to empty values as existing, but being needlessly incompatible with POSIX shells and older bash releases -- including those shipped with MacOS), then use `[[ ]]` -- which makes it unmistakably clear to readers that you're using bash-only syntax, and isn't prone to some obscure bugs which `test` or `[` (even the bash built-in form of them) are prone to when used in more than 2-arg form:

```
[[ -v shell_var_1 || -v shell_var_2 ]]
```

Comment: Thanks! Any reason why   
inline `[ -v shell_var_1 -o -v shell_var_2 ] `
does work at all?

Comment: @OptimizedCoder, because `[` is provided by a shell builtin unless you explicitly run `/usr/bin/[` or `command [` to request the external version.

Comment: @OptimizedCoder, ...the reason it's bug-prone in that case is that the issues described in the APPLICATION NOTES section of the POSIX spec for `test` apply to *any* implementation of the `test` specification, including the built-in one, whereas `[[` doesn't comply with that specification -- particularly by way of having its own parser support, and thus being able to distinguish unambiguously between data and syntax.

Comment: ...well, any implementation with the poorly-thought-out and now discouraged XSI extensions, that is.